# How to view httpd response log?

Tags: apache-httpd, logs, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon Linux EC2 instance running as my webserver.

If I view the latest access logs by running `sudo tail /etc/httpd/logs/access_log` I can see that there are requests coming from IPs that are clearly not friendly (out of the country and searching for phpmyadmin/phpmanager/curl vulnerabilities.

My application also keeps its own logs of access attempts and these same requests appear there with "access denied by server configuration" so things appear to be working as they should - but I would like to be able to view the responses to make sure.

Is there a log of the response that was returned? I cannot find anything in the same directory. If not, how can force apache to keep a log of the responses it sends?

**Example**

Here are the 2 most recent entries:

`81.23.8.162 - - [23/Jul/2017:15:01:57 +0000] "HEAD http://MYSERVERIP/phpmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
183.129.160.229 - - [23/Jul/2017:15:14:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 340 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"`

Comment: Above and beyond the HTTP response code?

Comment: I guess that's not necessary if the HTTP response code shows it has been handled appropriately. I've added the most recent lines from the log - does that the mean the first one was returned 404 and the second returned 302/340?

Comment: Ah, after reading more about the access logs I see that the first number is the code returned and the second is the size of the data returned. I should have read more on this before posting here.